# Highlight first element with condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet, highlight

I am looking for a function that can highlight only a line from an XML.

For example:

```
<DatabaseResult Result='Database transaction completed successfully.'>
<root>
<row Name='ABC1' Description='General 1' Quantity='1.000' UOM='ea' ID='1' Added='0'/>
<row Name='ABC2' Description='General 2' Quantity='1.000' UOM='ea' ID='2' Added='0'/>
<row Name='ABC3' Description='General 3' Quantity='1.000' UOM='ea' ID='3' Added='0'/>
</root>
</DatabaseResult>
```

I have the above mentioned XML and i need to display this information in a table. First, I need to highlight only the first line.
After the first line has been highlighted and action will be taken, the " Added " property will be updated from value 0 with value 1

The XML file will be updated with the new value/

After this the workflow re-enter to this XML using XSLT and shows table, now with with line 2 highlighted.

I tought about using an XSL function that use for example the following:
Will highlight only the first value that has Added = '0' and the value is greater than the first one.

```
      <xsl:if test="(@Added= '0') and (@ID= DatabaseResult/root/row/ID[not(. &gt; /DatabaseResult/root/row/ID)][1])">

      <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color: green</xsl:attribute>

        <tr style="text-align: center;">
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Name" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Description" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Quantity" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@UOM" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@ID" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Added" /></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Can you please advise what would be the best condition to use for the above mentioned case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By highlight do you mean display? Is it okay to do all at once without "reentering" the xslt? What is your desired output?

Comment: Can you display expected output?